# Statically resolved type parameters in F# do not resolve as expected, or: cannot propagate type parameters?

Tags: compiler-errors, f#, type-parameter

TLDR: how to repeat / propagate static type parameters in F#? For the below example function, I can't get it to work.

Here's a minimal (I think) version that exemplifies what I'm trying to achieve (i.e., a method that tests the range of a value based on statically known presences of `MinValue` and `MaxValue` properties on the type):

```
type MyByte = MyByte of byte with
    static member MinValue = MyByte Byte.MinValue
    static member MaxValue = MyByte Byte.MaxValue
    static member op_Explicit (MyByte x): int64 = int64 x
    static member op_Explicit (MyByte x): double = double x

let inline isWithinMinMaxRange< ^b, ^a when 
                    ^b: comparison 
                    and ^a: comparison 
                    and ^b: (static member MinValue: ^b) 
                    and ^b: (static member MaxValue: ^b)
                    and ^b : (static member op_Explicit: ^b -> ^a) > 
                    (value: ^a) =

    let minRange = ((^b) : (static member MinValue: ^b) ())
    let maxRange = ((^b) : (static member MaxValue: ^b) ())
    let cast v = (^b : (static member op_Explicit: ^b -> ^a) v)

    value > cast minRange && value < cast maxRange

// works as can be expected
let test() = isWithinMinMaxRange<MyByte, _> 256.0

// does not work, complains it cannot convert to 'a
let inline test2 v = isWithinMinMaxRange<MyByte, _> v
```

The above code throws a compile error on `test2`:

> error FS0043: The type 'MyByte' does not support a conversion to the type ''a'

So the problem here is: how to convince the compiler that we have such conversion? When I add a generic dummy function that throws, it compiles, but the compiler then **always** goes to that generic dummy function, it **does not resolve to choose the methods with the proper concrete types**.

If I try to fix this by repeating the constraints, it gets weirder (and way less readable):

```
let test< ^source, ^value
        when ^source: comparison 
        and ^value: comparison 
        // next line is redundant, but shows my experiments ;)
        and (^source or ^value) : (static member op_Explicit: ^value -> ^source)
        and ^source: (static member op_Explicit: ^source -> MyByte)
        and ^value: (static member op_Explicit: ^value -> sbyte) 
        and ^source: (static member MinValue: ^source) 
        and ^source: (static member MaxValue: ^source)> (v: ^value) =
    isWithinMinMaxRange< ^source, ^value> v
```

This gives the ominous errors:

> error FS0001: A type parameter is missing a constraint 'when  ^source : (static member op_Explicit :  ^source ->  ^?9104)'
>
> and
>
> error FS0043: A type parameter is missing a constraint 'when  ^source : (static member op_Explicit :  ^source ->  ^?9104)

My gut feeling is that somehow the compiler cannot statically figure out the proper types, so I tried all kinds of variants from my trickbook but after a while and fixing each of the "miss so on so constraint" errors one by one, I keep ending up with the above error.

Any help is much appreciated with these:

- Any idea how I can fix this while keeping the statically resolved constraints? (I know how to fix it with matching on the types dynamically, but I'm trying to prevent that)
- I've seen similar errors before and always managed somehow to fix them, but how can I interpret them? What is the type behind `^?9104` (my main project gives different numbers)?
- Why can't these type constraints be propagated? In my experience, usually copying the constraints solves any and all issues, unless the method is used in a more concrete manner, where they are resolved. But even when I make the constraints exactly equal on both functions, the same nasty error appears.

Comment: for anyone landing on this question and trying to solve it like I spent some time doing, you may save some time looking at the open bug on the exact problem : https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/3508